# For loop - expression result unused

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting this error:

```
Expression result unused
```

in this line:

```
  for(NSInteger i = 0; i lives; i++)
```

This is my code:

```
lives = 3;
heartArray = [ [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSInteger i = 0; i lives; i++)
{
    CCSprite *heart = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"heart.png"];
    [hearthArray insertObject:heart atIndex:i];
    heart.position = ccp( ((i+1)*50), winSize.height - 50);
    [self addChild:hearth];
}
```

Comment: Both your condition (i < lives), and `hearthArray addObject` seem suspicious. Condition is downright wrong, and I suppose `hearthArray` should be `heartArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. You should have `i < lives` in the second expression in your `for` loop.